# Spark structured streaming read messages from Kafka with varying schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read messages from a Kafka topic in a streaming manner. The messages in the topic have two types of schema.

```
1. { "Request": { <some nested json> } }
2. { "Response": { <different nested json> } }
```

One message has request schema and another response schema. How can I read these json messages in Spark, identify whether it's a Request message or a Response message and then take actions accordingly? Need to do this in Scala.

Comment: You should try deserialize as strings and use `get_json_object` function with filter functions to split different schemas. Alternatively, fix your schema to have `type` field, for example, with values "request/response", rather than a top level key